# Why does my BassBoost service not work in background :(?

Tags: android, service

I am trying to get the `BassBoost` class work in background. It works when the app is in front of my eyes, but when I press the back button, It does not bass boost anymore.

This is my code-

```
BassBoost bb;
...
 bb = new BassBoost(0, 0);
 bb.setEnabled(true);
bb.setStrength((short) 1000);
```

I also tried moving it to a service:

```
public class ServiceName extends Service {
public static BassBoost bb;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "service started dawg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    bb = new BassBoost(0, 0);
    bb.setEnabled(true);
    bb.setStrength((short) 1000);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

I even tried making my service sticky:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for example, I suppose you are having MainActivity.java file Place below code in onCreate method, at the end.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, watchman.class);
startService(intent);
Log.d(TAG, "Starting Service...\n");
```

Here watchman.class means you need to create watchman.java file. 
It should have atleast following basic code

```
public class watchman extends Service
{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
         return null;
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {


          new Thread(new Runnable()
          {
               public void run()
               {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Thread Running...");

                        // code in service goes here..


                        Thread.sleep(10000);

                    }

               }


         }).start();

    return START_STICKY;

   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy()
   {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "Service Destroyed...");

   }



}
```

In your manifest.xml file put following code before  tag

```
<service android:name=".watchman"></service>
</application>
```

Now auto include necessary import files and run project on emulator keeping logcat open .. You should see "Thread running" getting printed multiple time, actually infinite loop. It is intended to keep your code here..., which will keep running even if your application get closed.

Ask me if anything more help needed. Hope you or anybody find it helpful

Comment: are you saying I need to execute my code every second?

Comment: @myGrelax will you please post full code and let me and also other members have a look on it?

Comment: @myGrelax Upload full code with their filenames, perticularly mainactivity.java and manifest.xml and service.java